# writing a logic for .z.pg handler in q

Tags: kdb

I like to write a logic for .z.pg so when a remote client logs in from a port my table gets populated with certain information as such:

```
.ipc.history:enlist`time`handle`user`query`result!(0Np;0Ni;`;::;::)
```

so I write the following logic:

```
.z.pg:{[x] r:value x;`.ipc.history insert (.z.p;.z.w;.z.u;value x;r);r}
```

based on:

```
     .z.pg:{[x]0N!(`zpg;x);value x  }
```

I am assuming x to be the query like "1+1".

so when I listen on port:

```
q queryHistory1.q -p 5000
```

and the client does some query (r) on `handle:hopen 5000`; my table .ipc.history gets pupulated with the fields that it contains.

Though I do not get an error, my table is empty.

Comment: your code works fine. the only thing you are doing wrong is evaluating x twice, once with `r:value x` and once again with `value x`. but that doesn't affect the response to the user, nor the insert to the tracking table -- that all works fine

Comment: You might be interested in looking at Simons solutions here: https://github.com/simongarland/dotz He wrote a bunch of solutions around client tracking, usage tracking, access control etc. Or more recently Toms whitepaper here: https://code.kx.com/q/wp/permissions_with_kdb.pdf

Comment: so if I change "value x" to x within insert statement to populate `query column would that give me "1+1"? so the problem of my table not populating is else where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my own testing what you have appears to work as expected. Initially, without altering your code my table was populated with the following after making the query h"1+1" client side

```
time                          handle  user             query         result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                       ::            ::
2019.02.11D17:22:04.976012000 560    Liam McGrenaghan  2             2
```

Are you querying synchronously with a positive handle, or asynchronously with a negative handle? .z.pg works for the former whereas .z.ps works for the latter.There is also more useful information about using .z functions for monitoring at the following link. https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/using-dotz/.

Also, you probably want to show the raw query itself in the table rather than what the query evaluates to, if this is the case then just use.

```
.z.pg:{[x] r:value x;`.ipc.history insert (.z.p;.z.w;.z.u;x;r);r}
```

Where  x has replaced value x. This then returned a table that is probably more what you are looking for.

```
time                          handle user             query         result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019.02.11D17:24:25.008643000 560    Liam McGrenaghan "1+1"         2
```

Comment: Thanks I did change value x to x, and I am using positive handle.